# redis and redis-server packages

Tags: 18.04, redis

I would like to install `redis` server on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. 
I noticed there are two packages: [redis](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/redis) and [redis-server](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/redis-server).
Some documentation ([DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04) for example) suggests to use the redis-server package, other documentation instead (like [linuxconfig](https://linuxconfig.org/install-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) for instance) use the redis package. Is there any difference? The redis package depends only on the redis-server package, so probably I thought it might work as a simple link to the latter.

Comment: `redis` is probably a metapackage that installs `redis-server`, while `redis-server` is the actual software installation.  Can't verify but this is what it sounds like to me.

Comment: `redis` depends on `redis-server` so installing `redis` will also install `redis-server`. @ThomasWard is probably right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any actual confirmation, it's likely that `redis` is actually just what we call a **metapackage** - a package that does nothing but pull in another package as its dependency (or dependencies).

In this case, since `redis` installs `redis-server`, and `redis-server` actually contains the `redis` server bits, we can make the assumption that `redis` is just a metapackage that pulls in `redis-server`.

They're not *identical* per se, but they ultimately install the 'same thing' by pulling in the `redis-server` dependency when installing `redis`.